# PDF Template html generated

Tags: html, pdf

Is there any solutions in positioning images in PDF?
I'm making an HTML PDF template, then I've noticed that the margins code using inline styles doesn't work.
Also, i'm using tables other styles in PDF wont work also..

Please see link below..

https://www.diigo.com/item/image/3oxa5/dj8s?size=o

Comment: How do you convert the HTML to PDF are you using any program? Is this for using in a web app?

Comment: i'm using symfony framework . Have you seen the screenshot?

Comment: Easiest way to convert HTML to PDF https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ just make the HTML work in webkit and the PDF will be very accurate

Comment: there is a layout that im using and only i create an HTML tags on it .my problem here is only the positioning of the the divs or tables coz margins in HTML to PDF wont work